# ORACLE sql - JOINING TABLES

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with joining tables according to the ERD/Diagram provided. I did start it off alittle but I am having issues with joining the rest of the tables. 
This is what I did so far

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, username, post_title, comment_content
FROM profile_info p
JOIN club_member cm ON p.member_username = cm.username
JOIN blog_post bp ON cm.username = bp.member_username
JOIN post_comment pc ON bp.post_id = pc.post_id;
```

I want to join the POST_PROP, TAG_MEMBER_W_INTEREST and INTEREST. but i am so confused on how to do this. Please can someone help. Below is the diagram:

[image]

Also i am sorry I cannot post it other than a link because i do not have reputation points. If someone can edit this id appreciate it. Thank you.

UPDATE: I was able to join the 5 tables, now im left with two other tables which are POST_PROP and POST_COMMENT

```
--Profile info -> Club member -> Blog post -> TAG MEMBER INTEREST->INTEREST 
SELECT first_name, last_name, username, post_title,interest_tag
FROM profile_info p
JOIN club_member cm ON p.member_username = cm.username
JOIN blog_post bp ON cm.username = bp.member_username
JOIN tag_member_w_interest tg ON cm.username= tg.member_username
JOIN interest i ON tg.interest_id = i.interest_id;
```

Comment: Here's one: `JOIN POST_PROP PP ON pp.member_username = cm.username`. Whats the actual issue? Just join on likely looking fields.

Comment: Also, you should alias the columns in your select `select p.firstname, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to add

```
JOIN post_comment pc ON pc.member_username = cm.username
JOIN post_prop pp ON pp.member_username = cm.username
```

and got the following SQL select statement by binding through `member_username` column of `club_member` table

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, username, post_title, interest_tag
  FROM profile_info p
  JOIN club_member cm ON p.member_username = cm.username
  JOIN blog_post bp  ON cm.username = bp.member_username
  JOIN tag_member_w_interest tg  ON cm.username = tg.member_username
  JOIN interest i ON tg.interest_id = i.interest_id
  JOIN post_comment pc ON pc.member_username = cm.username
  JOIN post_prop pp ON pp.member_username = cm.username;
```

Comment: I thought of this before i saw your answer. Would this be correct?                                                                          
SELECT first_name, last_name, username, post_title, interest_tag, comment_content, prop_type
FROM profile_info p
JOIN club_member cm ON p.member_username = cm.username
JOIN blog_post bp ON cm.username = bp.member_username
JOIN tag_member_w_interest tg ON cm.username= tg.member_username
JOIN interest i ON tg.interest_id = i.interest_id
JOIN POST_COMMENT pc ON bp.post_id = pc.post_id
JOIN post_prop pp ON bp.post_id = pp.post_id;

Comment: @IllJasmine by looking through Foreign vs. Primary Key relations, that way of binding seems possible, also.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the response